# Is there a way to delete an entire array list of picture boxes (removing the images too) and create a new one?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an array list of picture boxes that I want to empty or delete and recreate whenever the player wants to reset the game. This array list holds the bullets fired by the player. I disabled all the timers for the game, including the one that moves the bullets before running this. This code should delete all the elements in an array list and create a new one:

```
for (int c = 0; c < bulletList.Count; c++)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(bulletList.ElementAt(c));
            bulletList.Remove(bulletList.ElementAt(c));
            bulletCount--;
        }

        bulletCount = 0;
        bulletList = new List<PictureBox>();
```

However, some of the images of the elements remain on the form, even though they have been deleted from the array list. Is there another, better way to delete an entire list of picture boxes or a fix to this problem?

Comment: Call the `Dispose()` method of the Controls. It will also remove them from the `Controls` collection.

Comment: @Jimi bulletList.ElementAt(c).Dispose(); did not fix the problem. Some images remain on the form after reset.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < bulletList.Count; i++) { bulletList[0].Dispose(); } bulletList.Clear();`

Comment: @Jimi Thank you so much! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Dipose() method of controls. So it would instead be

```
  for (int i = 0; i < bulletList.Count; i++) 
        {
            bulletList[i].Dispose(); 
        }

        bulletList.Clear();

        bulletCount = 0;
        bulletList = new List<PictureBox>();
```